# Boolean Logic Comparing Data From Two Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
          Date  Invoice          Name  Price  Coupon Location
0   2017-12-24   700349      John Doe  59.95    NONE    VAGG1
1   2017-12-24   700347     Joe Smith  59.95    GBMR       GG
2   2017-12-24   700345  Dave Johnson  35.00  CHANGE    VAGG1
3   2017-12-24   700342     Sue Davis  35.00  GADSLR    VAGG1
4   2017-12-23   700329   Betty Clark  84.95  GADSLR      GG2
```

and a second dataframe `df2`:

```
           Date  Invoice         Name  Price    Coupon    Location
0   2017-12-24    800349     John Doe  59.95   NONE      VAGG1
1   2017-12-24    800347    Joe Smith  59.95   GBMR      GG
2   2017-12-24    800345     John Doe  17.95   CHANGE    VAGG1
3   2017-12-24    800342     John Doe   9.95   GADSLR    VAGG1
4   2017-12-23    800329  Sue Simpson  34.95   GADSLR    GG2
```

I would like to create a third Dataframe, `df3`, using the following logic.

- For each name in `df1`, check to see if there is a match.
- If there is a match, add the matching row from `df2` to `df3`, provided
  that the price for that row does not match the price associated with
  that name if `df1`.

So the output dataframe, `df3`, should appear as follows:

```
+------------+---------+----------+-------+--------+----------+
|    Date    | Invoice |   Name   | Price | Coupon | Location |
+------------+---------+----------+-------+--------+----------+
| 2017-12-24 |  800345 | John Doe | 17.95 | CHANGE | VAGG1    |
| 2017-12-24 |  800342 | John Doe |  9.95 | GADSLR | VAGG1    |
+------------+---------+----------+-------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Is the match strictly on the `Name` column, not `Invoice`?

Comment: @ako Yes, you are correct. Only on ```Name```, not on ```Invoice```.

Comment: So you are asking, "for any row in df2 where Name is in df1, return that row if the price is different than in df1?" If so you could just merge df1 and df2 and then remove rows where `Price_y`==`Price_x`.

Comment: @ako, that sounds great. Any chance of posting that line of code as an answer? Because I'm still not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `merge` + `query` -

```
df1.merge(df2[['Name', 'Price']], on='Name')\
   .query('Price_x != Price_y')\
   .drop('Price_x', 1)\
   .rename(columns={'Price_y' : 'Price'})

         Date  Invoice      Name Coupon Location  Price
1  2017-12-24   700349  John Doe   NONE    VAGG1  17.95
2  2017-12-24   700349  John Doe   NONE    VAGG1   9.95
```

Where `df1` and `df2` are your respective dataframes.

Comment: @COLDSPEED When I try to run your code I get the following error: ```KeyError: "['Name' 'Price'] not in index"```.

Comment: There was actually some extra spaces around the keys, which I removed. Once those were gone I set df3 = to your line of code. The result is an empty dataframe.

Comment: @HMLDude Need more information. If it works for this sample, but not for your actual data, then make sure your dtypes match up.

Answer (score 1):

The following code block:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name', how='right')\
        .query('Price_x != Price_y')\
        .drop('Price_x', 1)\
        .rename(columns={'Price_y' : 'Price'})
```

Results in `df3 =`

```
            Date_x  Invoice_x         Name Coupon_x Location_x        Date_y  \
1   2017-12-24   700349.0     John Doe     NONE      VAGG1   2017-12-24
2   2017-12-24   700349.0     John Doe     NONE      VAGG1   2017-12-24
4          NaN        NaN  Sue Simpson      NaN        NaN   2017-12-23

   Invoice_y  Price  Coupon_y  Location_y
1     800345  17.95   CHANGE    VAGG1
2     800342   9.95   GADSLR    VAGG1
4     800329  34.95   GADSLR    GG2
```

The extended code block:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Name', how='right')\
        .query('Price_x != Price_y')\
        .drop('Price_x', 1)\
        .rename(columns={'Price_y' : 'Price'})\
        .drop('Location_x',1)\
        .drop('Coupon_x',1)\
        .drop('Date_x',1)\
        .drop('Invoice_x',1)\
        .rename(columns={'Date_y' : 'Date'})\
        .rename(columns={'Invoice_y' : 'Invoice'})\
        .rename(columns={'Coupon_y' : 'Coupon'})\
        .rename(columns={'Location_y' : 'Location'})
```

Results in `df3 =`

```
          Name          Date  Invoice  Price    Coupon    Location
1     John Doe   2017-12-24    800345  17.95   CHANGE    VAGG1
2     John Doe   2017-12-24    800342   9.95   GADSLR    VAGG1
4  Sue Simpson   2017-12-23    800329  34.95   GADSLR    GG2
```

Which is problematic because it results in column rows which are out of order. With the addition of:

```
df3=df3[['Date', 'Invoice', 'Name', 'Price', 'Coupon', 'Location']]
```

We get `df3 =`

```
           Date  Invoice         Name  Price    Coupon    Location
1   2017-12-24    800345     John Doe  17.95   CHANGE    VAGG1
2   2017-12-24    800342     John Doe   9.95   GADSLR    VAGG1
4   2017-12-23    800329  Sue Simpson  34.95   GADSLR    GG2
```

Which is close to the desired answer, except for the "Sue Simpson" entry, which should be absent.